# GitHub Pages show only header and footer

Tags: html, reactjs, github, github-pages

My repo: https://github.com/Teslachinator/portfolio-you

When you go to the site, only the header and footer is shown, to download the content you need to click on the button, what is the problem? Connected using gh-pages

I tried to change the home page link, but all to no avail.

`"homepage": "https://...github.io/portfolio-you//"`

```
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
      <Route path="/project/:id" element={<Projectt />} />
      <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

Comment: You have to use `HashRouter` if you want to host react website on gh pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather around looking at your code the GitHub web works just fine only you haven't declared a component to be rendered at the stating route 'portfolio-you/' and for that you see a blank screen with only the Header and the Footer and for the other route you see just what you expected